# Rounding currency to add up to the total value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have a sales tax value that I need to divide evenly across 3 items.
For example: `$153.88/3 = 51.29333333333333`

When rounded to 2 decimal places to represent currency, `it = $51.29`.
However `$51.29*3=$153.87` which is 1 cent off from the total tax amount.

Is there a function to solve for these rounding errors so that the individual values always add up to the total? So that extra 1 cent is randomly allocated to 1/3 items?

```
select '1' as item_number, 153.88 as sales_tax, round(153.88 /3,2) as rounded
union all
select '2' as item_number, 153.88 as sales_tax, round(153.88 /3,2) as rounded
union all
select '3' as item_number, 153.88 as sales_tax, round(153.88 /3,2) as rounded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky problem.  It is simple enough to use `floor()`, `ceil()`, or `round()` to get an *approximate* solution.  You can then even add the "extra" to one of the rows.

However the extra might be more than 0.01 and that starts to looks awkward.  This doesn't happen when you have three items, but it can happen with more.  I prefer to distribute these evenly over the rows.

So, I recommend:

```
with t as (
      select '1' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '2' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '3' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '4' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '5' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '6' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
      union all
      select '7' as item_number, 153.89 as sales_tax
)
select t.*,
       (floor(sales_tax * 100 / count(*) over ()) +
        (case when floor(sales_tax * 100 / count(*) over ()) * count(*) over () +
                   row_number() over ()  - 1 < sales_tax * 100
              then 1 else 0
         end)
       ) / 100.0
from t;
```

I've included an example where the distribution makes a difference.

Comment: very good point here with the extra not always being .01. thanks for flagging - this is great!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below

```
select * except(pre_split, pos), 
  round(if(pos > round(100 * (sales_tax - sum(pre_split) over()), 2), 
    pre_split, pre_split + .01)
  , 2) final_split
from (
  select *, 
    round(sales_tax / count(1) over(), 2) pre_split,
    row_number() over(order by rand()) pos
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

next run output

[image]

yet next run ...

[image]

So, as you can see  - extra cent is applied randomly - as randompy as rand() function operates  :o))

Also, in case of more than just one cent - all cents will be applied evenly and randomly too

Comment: this is just what i needed, thank you so much!